# Likes in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata, database

Here my problem: I'd like to create a network which allows users to upload posts and like them.

I think i can store each post in a single collection called 'post', and i don't have problems in doing it.

But where can i store likes on each post with related data (time, userfrom etc..)? 
I can't do it inside post document because maximum size of a document is 16MB, and imagining i'll have to record thousands of likes with related data for each post i can't do this.

I could relate each post to a collection, which includes documents and each document is a like. But i honestly prefer not to create millions and millions of collection if possible.

Example of a post document:

`{_id: blabla, userfrom: {}, txt: "i am the post", time: {}, geo: {}, likes: {here i have to add as many likes as users clicks, and it can exceed 16MB}}`

now in 'likes' i can put a reference to a collection, but this is what i'd like not to do.

I read about gridstore in mongodb but i didn't get the point. can i use it as a document which size can tend to infinite? So that i can add as many records as i want? So with grid store can i do something like:

`{_id: blabla, userfrom: {}, txt: "i am the post", time: {}, geo: {}, likes: {infinite records}}`

Can someone help me dealing with it? Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "create millions and millions of collection". The common approach would be to create one collection with one document for each like, containing a reference to the post the like it is referring to. Why would that not work?

Comment: Why not store the likes as documents? Each would have a reference id for the post they had liked? And, keep a count of the totals in the post so the code doesn't actually need to get a count each time. I'd bet you won't need to get the details of each "like" every time a post is displayed, so it's best not to store all of the data in one document anyway.

Comment: Do you mean creating a collection for each posts or a single collection in which to put all likes from all posts? @AndreasHultgren

Comment: This is what i'd like to do, but i don't know where to store all that documents. In a single collection or in different collections for different posts? @WiredPrairie

Comment: Single collection. Each like would need a field called something like `postId` which could be used in a query to fetch all of the likes for a given post.

Comment: You might also choose to double store the most recent likes, in a collection of all likes, but also in the original post document. Say, for example, storing the last 50 so they can be fetched with the post every time.

Comment: Thank you guy you gave me the right inspiration. One more thing.. querying among few documents and querying among lots of documents is the same for mongodb? i mean.. looking for a document with a certain id in a collection of 100 documents takes the same time of looking for a document with certain id in a collection of 1 million documents? @WiredPrairie

Comment: Index the field using ensureIndex and it should be fast.

Comment: Guy i have taken a look at creating indexes in mongodb but i can't understand when to do it! Each time i add a like (so a document) for example do i have to ensureindex of that collection? @WiredPrairie

Comment: No, you just call ensureIndex once with the fields you want to index.

Comment: Guy i am sorry to ask again, but i have read on mongodb doc that maximum number of indexes for a single collection is 64. so how could i ensureIndex of each posts? @WiredPrairie

Comment: The index applies for all documents in a collection

Comment: so is enough i ensure once the field which contains reference to posts? @WiredPrairie

Comment: @Morrisda: Yes, ensuring an index once on a collection will index all current and future documents for that collection (until you drop the index).  The fields to include will depend on your common queries.  For more details see the [Indexing Tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/) in the MongoDB manual.

Answer (score 5):

When you don't want to embed the likes, you have to go the relational way.

Create another collection "likes" where each document has a field which says which post it applies to. To avoid having to count all entries from the likes-collection to get the number of likes of a post, you should also store the current count in the post-documents.

Regarding GridFS: I don't think it will help you here. It is not supposed to be used for documents. Its purpose is to store large binary files in the database.

Comment: If we store the current count in the post-documents then we'll need to update that count every time a user likes or dislikes that post. Don't think its the best idea to update a document millions of times as the data won't remain consistent between post and the likes table.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh What will happen more frequently in your application: A user *sees* the likes-number or a user *changes* the likes-number? The more frequent case is the one you should optimize for. And I am very certain that this number will be read a lot more often than it is written. I am also quite certain that documents with *millions* of likes are rather the exception than the norm and the majority of documents will have far smaller numbers of like's, but those with millions of likes will still be those with the most views. But it's your application.

Comment: Yes you make a very valid point. I won't comment further because I don't know a better solution but it would be great to know if a there's a better solution to this. This seems to be very common problem (Likes) but I've yet to come across a really good implementation.