# Mongodb - most efficient way to structure my db?

Tags: mongodb

I'm a bit new to mongodb and I'm trying to setup a simple server where I will have users, posts, comments, like and dislikes, among some things. What I'm wondering is which way this should be setup most efficiently?

Should I have one table for likes where I add userId and postId (more or less same for the dislike and comments table)

Or would it be better if likes, dislikes and comments are parts of the post? Like:

```
//Post structure
{
    "_id":"kljflskds",
    "field1":"content",
    "field2":"content",
    "likes":[userId,userId,userId],
    "dislikes":[userId,userId,userId],
    "comments":[{comment object},{comment object},{comment object}]
}
```

Because for each post when I retreive them I would like to know how many likes it has, how many dislikes and how many comments. With the first version I would either need to multiple queries on the server(unnecessary processor power?) or on the phone(unnecessary bandwidth). But the second would only need one query. I believe the second option with having comments as a part of the posts seems more efficient, but I'm not a pro so I'd like to hear what other people think of this?

Comment: In object oriented databases, there is no table. With some tricks, you could have comments outside of the posts but query the posts with comments in only one request. Collections don't have to contain the same objects, for that reasons you could save the comments and the posts in the same collection and query everything once. Also, having comments outside makes it possible to query a certain amount of comments.

Comment: Are you tied to mongo here? I think a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) like Neo4j is more suited for these kind of datamodels.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix if I keep everything in one collection could I for instance query which posts has the most comments? Or get a user with total likes from all posts?

Comment: @RickyA that looks interesting, I can't do it for this project at this point, but I will for sure check it for future project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Likes in mongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216718/likes-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, there are no tables in a document-oriented database. What you'll also find is that unlike a relational database where there is often a 'right way' to structure the database, the same is not true with MongoDB. Your schema should be structured based on how you're going to access the information most regularly. Documents are extremely flexible, unlike rows in tables.

You could create a comments collection or have them directly in the post documents. Two considerations would be: 1. Will you need to access the comments without accessing the post? and 2. Are your documents going to get too big and unwieldy?

In both of these cases with your blog, it most likely would be better to nest the comments as most of your traffic will be searching for posts, and you'll be pulling all of the comments related to the post. Also, a comment will not be owned by multiple tables; besides, MongoDB isn't meant to be denormalized like a relational database, so having duplicate information in multiple documents (i.e. tag names, city names, etc.) is normal.

Also, having a collection for `likes` is a very 'relational' way of thinking. In MongoDB, I can't think of a use case where you'd want a `likes` collection. When you're coming from the relational world, you really have to step back and rethink how you're creating your database because you'll be constantly fighting it otherwise.

With only two collections, `posts` and `users`, getting the information that you're looking for would be trivial, as you can just get the count of the likes and comments and they're all right there.

Comment: Mmmm, 16mb document limit comes to mind. Also the cost of updating a document. Not ideal.

Comment: Well, if it is very popular the `likes` array will fill it for you.